# Why is it not necessary to close this brace?

Tags: syntax

When I compile the following document, I get no error

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\foo}{foo}

\begin{document}
Why is \foo{ indifferent about its closing brace?
\end{document}
```

yet there is no `}` for `\foo`. Using `\newcommand*` makes no difference. The document compiles identically to if the closing brace had been present.

Comment: Good question. My guess is that opening braces that are unmatched at the end of the document are ok. Note that it has nothing to do with your `\newcommand`. The following code produces the same effect. \documentclass{article} \begin{document} Why is { indifferent about its closing brace? \end{document}

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`\foo` is defined without arguments, so TeX does not look for any. Often, `{}<space>` is used to "terminate" the control sequence for macros without arguments (like this: `\foo{}<space>`), producing the expansion of the macro plus a trailing space, but this is by no means required, and `\foo\<space>` accomplishes the same thing.

From that point, since the brace was not used to delimit an argument, `{` enters a group, which is reported in the log file:

> ```
> ### simple group (level 1) entered at line 6 ({)
> ```

Then, the document ends before the group is closed (which is not an error), which is also reported in the log file:

> ```
> (\end occurred inside a group at level 1)
> ```

---

For some reason, trailing spaces are not shown in inline code fragments here, so I have marked these with `<space>` because they are important to the discussion at hand. In the actual code, of course, `<space>` is a single space character.